# C Win32 Api: Update Edit box when finished editting

Tags: c, winapi

In my program, there would be a chance edit box, which changes the "drop rate" or "win rate"

But I would like to change it in such a way that if the user inputs a number higher than 100 and clicks out of the edit box, it the edit box text would change back into 100.

I have no idea how to implement this.

Comment: Some sample code would be helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following [tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html)

You will have to use WM_COMMAND in your callback function to catch the messages/notifications that your edit box sends (for instance EN_CHANGE).

Then you can check the value inside the callback and revert to 100 if it's too high.

For further reference all edit control notifications are listed on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, I do know about the message and I want to change it when the user clicks OUT of the edit box

Comment: How about the notification EN_KILLFOCUS?

Comment: This makes for an extremely annoying UI, as it disallows entering data, that's **temporarily** invalid. And doing your input validation on focus change is just wrong: [WM_KILLFOCUS is the wrong time to do field validation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040419-00/?p=39753).